# Entity Framework performance issues adding child to list

Tags: c#, list, performance, entity-framework, addition

I am working on a project where we are using Entity Framework 6.1.3. Right now we are experiencing pretty big performance issues when adding a child object to a list of the parent entity (see code sample below).

We are using lazy-loading, so what I noticed is that everything works fine until we call `_parent.Children.Add(child);` since it seems to load all children from the database just to be able to add a new one. Since some of our parent objects have about 50,000 children, this is delaying this simple insert call by 7-8 seconds and sometimes even causing timeouts.

To me it doesn't really make sense for Entity Framework to load all children just in order to add one, so is there a way I can avoid this or is this an Entity Framework design-flaw and should we find a workaround?

I'd obviously like to find a solution for this and would prefer not having to implement pure ADO queries for this one problem.

Thanks!

```
public class Parent 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class ParentAggregate
{
    private readonly Parent _state;

    public ParentAggregate(Parent state)
    {
        _state = state;
    }

    public void AddChild(Guid id)
    {
        var child = new Child { Id = id };
        _state.Children.Add(child);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is adding the `Child` to `DbSet<Child>` directly an option? Can't answer exactly why `Add` enumerates the collection, but to avoid it, you could do the relation on the other side if you have something like `ParentId` in your `Child` and then save the entity separately from its parent.

Comment: Have you correctly mapped the relation between Parent and Child? See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109363/parent-and-child-link-in-entity-framework

Comment: the getter required for the execution of _state.Children.Add does implicitly load the collection via lazy loading. Your only bet is to add the child to its DbSet and set a exposed FK property if you want to avoid calling the getter.

Comment: As an alternative, you could simply save the child directly (setting the proper parent reference of parentId) without adding it to a parent's collection, esp. with these large collections.

Comment: @GertArnold I agree but that approach doesn't always fit into the architectural approach used. Like in my example where I am accessing the parent in a DDD-kind-of-style where I do not have access to any repository or dbContext.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To me it doesn't really make sense for Entity Framework to load all children just in order to add one

The lazy loading occurs the first time you *access* a navigation property through its *getter*. And the sample code

```
_parent.Children.Add(child);
```

consists of two operations:

(1) retrieve the `Children` property (through the property *getter*!):

```
var children = _parent.Children;
```

(2) perform some operation on it (call `Add` method in this case):

```
children.Add(child);
```

The lazy loading occurs because of the operation (1). As you can see, EF has nothing to do with that because it has no control over it. And there is no way to know what you are going to do with that property value - enumerate it, take a count or use `Add`, `Remove` etc. methods.

Here are some solutions.

First, why using lazy loading at all? It has so many side effects and inefficiencies, and all they can easily be solved by EF provided out of the box eager loading via `Include` methods. That's why by default EF Core ("the future of EF") does not use lazy loading by default and requires a special package and procedure for enabling it.

Second, if you insist using lazy loading, then you have the following two options:

(A) Disable lazy loading during the data modifications (requires access to/control of the `DbContext` instance):

```
dbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
_parent.Children.Add(child);
dbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
```

This also requires the collection property to be initialized in order to avoid NRE.

(B) Use explicit backing field and provide some direct access to it (to avoid triggering the lazy load by property accessor). For instance:

```
public class Parent 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    private ICollection<Child> children;
    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get => children; set => children = value; }

    public void Add(Child child)
    {
        // use the backing field directly
        if (children == null) children = new HashSet<Child>();
        children.Add(child); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I knew lazy loading occurs when you access a navigation property but for some reason I still thought it'd wait until the end before doing anything. Like I would expect a `_state.Children.FirstOrDefault()` only to launch one query that fetches one record, rather than fetching all and returning the first. Guess I was wrong! :-)

Comment: It's different. `IQueryable` interface is one of the few (if not the only one) which allows both lazy evaluation and transformation at runtime (because is based on expression tree and known methods). And EF has control over it. All other constructs are plain C# (imperative) language statements.

Comment: I went for approach B. Personally I think lazy-loading does have an added value in my solution. I have no access to the DbContext during the data modification, so approach B solved all my problems. The performance improvement in the application is HUGE. Thanks!